NextJS Auth0 add JWT token to client side requests
I Have a NextJS 14 SSR app, which uses Auth0 for authentication, using the @auth0/nextjs-auth0 library to manage authentication. I also have an external .Net Api with protected endpoints that validates incoming JWTs against Auth0.
I want to be able to hit my external Api from the client side of my Next app without having to go through a server action to get and populate authorization header of my request every time, as this is causing me to have to duplicate a lot of the Api endpoints in server actions on my Next app which seems like a waste of time, and would ideally be able to reduce the request by a hop going from  client->server->api to client->api.
I've read that setting HttpOnly cookie could be the solution to this however I'm not sure about refreshing the token when it expires.
I'm currently routing to the server for each request that requires authentication.
I have tried to update the handleAuth method in api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts to set the token on response
export const GET = handleAuth({
  login: async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
    try {
 await handleLogin({
        authorizationParams: {
          audience: "httplogin: async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      // Call the default login handler
      await handleLogin({
        authorizationParams: {
          audience: "https://localhost:3000",
          scope: "openid profile email offline_access",
        },
        returnTo: "/",
      })(req, res);      
     
      const accessTokenResult: GetAccessTokenResult = await getAccessToken(
        req as any,
        res as any
      );

      if (accessTokenResult && accessTokenResult.accessToken) {
        // Set the JWT as an HTTP-only cookie
        res.setHeader(
          "Set-Cookie",
          `Authorization=Bearer ${accessTokenResult.accessToken}; HttpOnly; Secure; Path=/; SameSite=Strict`
        );
        res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/" });
        res.end();
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login error:", error);    
    }

But handleLogin doesnt seem to be called or at least completes before the re-route to auth0's authentication portal, and therefore GetAccessTokenResult fails because the user isn't logged in/doesnt have a session when it tries to grab the token.
I'm sure if this is the correct approach or not, any
advice appreciated, thanks.
